# Calling HTTPS JBoss service from C# code throws an authentication error

Tags: c#, web-services, jboss

I'm trying to call a JBoss service from a C# program and I'm getting an annoyingly vague error.

```
            JbossService proxy = new JbossService();
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ME", "thepwd");
            proxy.Url = //https url snipped
            proxy.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            proxy.PreAuthenticate = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Calling service...");
            queryResponse qr = proxy.query();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

The exception and inner exception thrown are as follows:

exception : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

inner exception : Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

I'm not quite sure what this means, other than perhaps that JBoss likes me even less than I like it.  I'm calling from the local machine so I don't think it's a networking issue.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What kind of service is that? To me, the problem is clearly that you are not using the proper credentials ("ME/thepwd"). So, I'd try to consume this service manually, if possible.

Comment: I removed the credentials I'm using.  The ones I actually use I have confirmed are correct.

Comment: I've not consumed a JBoss service manually before.  Is there any particular trick to doing so?

Comment: Depends, that's why I asked what kind of service is that :-)

Comment: What kinds of service could it be?  I don't know much about JBoss.

Comment: Please as much info as you can. Do you see the service in the jxm-console http://jbosshost:8080/jmx-console   ? Can you call the service from the Java code? Do you see any error messages / exeptions in jboss log file, if yes, put them into your question

Comment: What is the HTTP response code from the server?  If you don't know, install www.fiddler2.com/ and check to see what the server is returning.  That should help narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when your client cannot verify trust over https with the server (usually because the server certificate is self signed or if it is signed by a root authority not installed on your client machine.

Easy fix (although there are security consequences)....somewhere in your initialization code add the following:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true;};
```

Basically this replaces the  application wide handling of server certificate validation and causes your application to accept any certificate.  If you want to get finer grained, you can examine the certificate and put some logic in the method.

This works for anything based on System.Net, so it should work for Web Services and any thing based on WebRequest.

Comment: Do you know if it would do the same if I requested a SSL connection and the JBoss server wasn't configured to accept it?

Comment: Short answer, no, my answer will not solve that issue since the ServerCertificateValidationCallback is only invoked after a connection is made and while the client and server are negotiating SSL.  In the case where the server isn't configured to handle https requests, it will simply refuse connection.  On the client, the only way to handle that is to attempt https, and if it fails, attempt http (if you're security environment permits it).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used JBOSS. This is how I troubleshoot similar problems, when using Microsoft technologies -- the same issues may be affecting your program:

- Firewall settings or network issue (try connecting manually, to rule this out)
- Self-service certificate issues:

  - Check the following certificate values:

    - Ensure the server's certificate issuer has a valid, matching issuing trusted root Certificate Authority (CA), on the same machine
    - The server certificate subject name matches the machine name exactly
    - The machine name the client is accessing matches that defined in the server certificate
    - An administrator account set (server) certificate thumbprint
  - Try recreating the SSL Certificate on both servers)
  - Try creating your own CA cert, add to trusted publishers, and then create an SSL sert based on that